# Firestore time execution to write/read is unstable after multiple executions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a `cloud function gen1` that is triggered by `pubsub event`, this topic receives all iot devices telemetries and the function is called about 5x/s, each call has a device id and this id is a document on firestore, each device id send messages every **10s**. It's working fine most of the time, with a durantion of **~300ms**, but sometimes the reading or writting operations take so long... some cases about **19s** just for reading check the prints bellow:

###### Slow execution

[image: Slow execution]

###### Slow logs

[image: slow logs]

###### Normal execution

[image]

###### Firestore debug logs

[image]

In these logs shows a difference of **10s** just to read a simple document

###### Cloud function environment:

- First Gen.
- Node18
- firebase-admin: v11.11.0
- 512MB
- us-central

###### Firestore:

- nam5

just to antecipate, I've already setted the flag `preferRest` and nothing change, and It's not memory this function only takes 120MB and the config was set to 512MB.

Thanks!

I expect that operations of read and write from firestore keep stable, bellow then *(~100ms)*, after multiple executions.

###### Firestore write timeout [Edit]

Add one more evidence of Firestore is slow to peform CRUD operations. The cloud functions was in hot start in this case
[image]

Comment: While `preferRest` definitely is a good idea, I still expect that this may be caused by cold starts on new instances. You may want to add a global variable that you set at the end of function runs, and then check if the longer execution times correlate to when the variable isn't set yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FrankvanPuffelen I will try that! But I think that some part of my code do that inderectly, There is a console.log in the start of connection, that reads env variables, that warns about the environment, if it is production or development. When a cold start happens shows the log otherwise not. Do you recommend to set minimal instances > 0?

Comment: I have too little information to make any recommendation. If you think your code is causing the problem, then please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which any of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Performance problems are notoriously hard to troubleshoot through Stack Overflow, but without code the best we can do is give general guidance like what I commented above.

Comment: I don't think it is the code, because the most of the time is spent on firestore operations like is shown in the **Firestore debug logs** "section" for this example the total time function execution was *10665ms* and firestore spent *10566ms* in this case to read, sometimes happens to write, and the fun fact is this also occurs after first read. For example I have three CRUD operations in my function, two reads and one write, the second read can be the 10s over.

Comment: News about the first tip that you gave, It is a cold start indeed. I just saw it right now! Any advice?

Comment: Too soon to celebrate, Now I had a hot start with a slow write ~3980 ms